# MySQL infinite INSERT VALUES

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am having problems with MySQL. I have an INSERT INTO *table* VALUES query, and after adding the values, I noticed I messed one of them up, and now it isn't letting me get out of the add value query. Please help.[image]

Comment: Why downvote the question?

Comment: It isn't exactly a programming question. Did you try to stop things with Ctrl-C or so? Or try typing `');`

Comment: @Adder This fixed my issue. Thank you.

Comment: It is actually a programming question. This is a question directly linked to a programming tool and while Ctrl+C solves it, and can be argued that it isn't a programming "way", so is yanking the power chord to the computer. However, the *syntax* of the query *is* related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered.

Fixed by using `');`.

Suggested by @Adder.